# How to delete a file in UFT?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am access files in a folder through a for loop lie this

```
For Each f in re.files
    If .... Then
        --Here I want to delete the file f
```

How do I delete that file f? I dont need to do it inside the loop, I can refer to it outside and delete

Answer (score 1):

Given a file object (via .GetFile or loop over .Files), use its [.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k4wket3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method. If you have a path (string), consider to use the [.DeleteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/thx0f315%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method of the FileSystemObject.